# Вывод изображения на дисплей

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Установил на Raspberry Pi вот такой дисплей (http://ozzmaker.com/piscreen-quick-start-guide/) - все работает, все ок.

Мне нужно написать скрипт на Python, который я смогу запускать с SSH, но отображаться он будет

- На этом дисплее
- В полном экране

Как это можно сделать? Спасибо.

Comment: вы хотите, чтобы ваша ssh сессия (зашли с другого компьютера e.g., laptop) дублировалась бы на экране raspberry-pi? (`screen -x ssh`— [Is there a way to make an SSH session act like a local terminal session?](https://superuser.com/q/882127/13868))¶ Скрипт у вас требует X? Вы хотите двигая мышь локально (на laptop откуда ssh запускаете), чтобы её движения отображались бы на экране RPi (virtual KVM, synergy) или достаточно просто `$DISPLAY` поменять?¶ Для сравнения, `ssh -X` позволяет запустить GUI программу на RPi и работать с ней на laptop.

Comment: можно ли запустить питон на этом контроллере? Если да, то вам надо через API выводить картинки, а запускаться скриптом который запускают через ssh. Какие у вас проблемы возникли на этом пути?

Answer (score 1):

Запускайте chromium в режиме инфо-киоска, пишите логику на JS, и показывайте что хотите - хоть картинки, хоть мультики.

Обсуждают люди [тут](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=8298). Но все в общем просто - можно вообще вместо GUI на старте загрузить chromium - см по первой ссылке и [тут](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75296/launch-a-gui-browser-on-server-without-a-gui).

P.S. Поскольку возникли недопонимания, где здесь питон и ssh, поясняю - инфо-киоски на базе Chromium - общепринятая практика. Браузер имеет достаточно механизмов для селективного показа контента (картинок, текста, видео, слайд-шоу и пр.), реализации активного пользовательского интерфейса (DHTML и пр.), запроса к внешним и локальным ресурсам (в том числе и к программам на питоне - через AJAX/WSGI, если возникает необходимость), реакции на внешние события (websockets) и пр. и пр.

P.S.2. В целом опыт использования RasPI для инфо-киосков довольно противоречивый - иногда не хватает графических возможностей, даже рендеринг картинок высокого разрешения может вызывать проблемки. 
В качестве альтернативы предложу [ODROID XU4](http://www.hardkernel.com/main/products/prdt_info.php) ($60), [ASUS Tinker](https://www.asus.com/Single-Board-Computer/Tinker-Board/) ($60), [UP-BOARD](http://www.up-board.org/) ($90+) - немного дороже но стоит того, ASUS например поддерживает 4k экраны.

Comment: как это отвечает на вопрос: *"Python скрипт, запущенный по ssh, отображаемый на RPi экране?"*

Comment: @jfs я просто делюсь своим опытом - как человек может получить то что он ищет, просто другими способами - питон для этого не нужен, если у человека возникнут вопросы и-или сомнения - я думаю он о них сообщит, удачи

Comment: можете явно в ответе упомянуть какую именно вы проблему решаете, если это не задача, которая в вопросе описана? Допустим при включении RPi у вас chromium на установленном экране отобразился — дальше что? (как вы управлять им собираетесь? (по/без ssh)

Comment: Я всё объяснил, кроме того приведены ссылки на развернутое обсуждение задач, аналогичные тем, которые я и автор решаем.  То что можно написать на питоне, любую логику показа картинок, можно реализовать и на JS, если же нужно вызвать питон - разворачивается локальный apache и делаются любые вызовы из JS. Я подобные задачи решал, знаю о чем говорит автор - а можно спросить какую именно цель вы преследуете задавая здесь такие вопросы?

Comment: я не понимаю, какое отношение ваш ответ имеет к вопросу. Автор спрашивает о Питоне, вы говорите *"пишите логику на JS"*. Автор о *"запускать с SSH"*, вы говорите о *"запускайте chromium"*
 —каким боком локально запущенный chromium к ssh относится? Вы предлагаете к RPi экрану мышку/клавиатуру подключить и так управлять или вы рассматриваете только неинтерактивные приложения, то есть запустили chromium с какой-нибудь страничкой, а дальше как на телевизор с одним каналом смотрите?¶ На Stack Overflow суть ответа должна быть в самом ответе. Ссылки это дополнение к ответу, а не сам ответ.

Comment: Я всё объяснил, предложил как решить задачу а не как на питоне 3 строчки написать, предполагаю что для автора это важнее чем 3 строчки на питоне ;-) что мне поделать если вы не понимаете чего-то? страдать? :-)

Comment: @jfs, по-моему в данном случае - это весьма полезный ответ (если кроме ссылок (ссылки могут перестать работать) добавить описание), который может показать альтернативный (лучший) подход для решения задачи. Это также может пригодиться другим, тем кто думают, что данную задачу можно решить только при помощи Python. По поводу того, что ссылки сами по себе мало полезны - согласен...

Comment: @MaxU: *"альтернативный (лучший) подход для решения задачи"* в чём именно по вашему задача состоит (если не только заголовок вопроса читать) и как данный ответ её решает  (работает ли chromium с framebuffer?) (пишите даже те вещи, которые вам кажутся очевидными). В общем случае, chromium + JS полезны и для чисто локальных приложений (как свидетельствует появление electron. Хотя electron-приложения могут быть тяжёлыми даже для desktop. Кто-то любит один язык везде использовать, как свидетельствует react native для mobile), только не ясно какое отношение chromium имеет к текущему вопросу.

Comment: @jfs, [если я правильно понял  - framebuffer можно отключить...](http://ozzmaker.com/enable-x-windows-on-piscreen/). Вопрос, по-моему, если рассуждать логически, в том чтобы использовать PiScreen и что-то мне подсказывает не для того чтобы консольный output на нем смотреть... А как вы поняли данный вопрос? Для чего по-вашему автор собирается использовать PiScreen?

Comment: @MaxU: Вместо попыток чтения мыслей автора, я комментарий под вопросом оставил.¶ *"в том чтобы использовать PiScreen"* это конечно верно, но не слишком информативно (Ответ "... где мы? - На воздушном шаре" что в контексте анекдота также абсолютно верно, но также не слишком информативно). Если нет желания, то можете конечно не отвечать в чём по вашему задача в вопросе состоит и как именно её данный ответ решает.¶ Вы ссылку привели с какой целью? Я не вижу слова chromium в ней. Проще вопрос задам: утверждаете ли вы, что chromium можно с приведённым  в вопросе железом использовать? (да/нет).

Comment: @jfs, не надо занудствовать. Автор данного ответа попытался указать на альтернативный взгляд на вопрос (не мне вам объяснять что такое "XY Problem").

Comment: @MaxU: вы пытаетесь уйти от ответа на вопросы, которые я уже дважды формулировал выше (не буду "занудствовать" и повторять их). Если вы знаете ответы, то явно их укажите (можно кратко, вопрос про chromium это да/нет). Если не знаете, то не страшно: вы просто поддержали "лучшее" решение, не имея всех фактов -- все ошибаются.

Comment: уважаемые коллеги, в вопросе действительно никак не указано каким образом автор собирается применять сие устройство, исходя однако из моего опыта и из назначения дисплея я рискнул предположить что это характерный инфо-киоск и поделился своим практическим опытом как это делается в абсолютном большинстве случаев, и кстати - ElectronJS при этом очень часто применяется. Если автор имел в виду что-то другое, он вероятно сообщит о нерелевантности ответа, но в любом случае я считаю что мой опыт имеет какую-то ценность - как вариант отвлечься от любимого мною питона и подумать о жизни :-)